# "variable" May be undefined or defined from star imports: tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a simple outline for a gui, and I'm getting the warning 
"variable" May be undefined or defined from star imports: tkinter for all of my variables.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

class myApp :
    def __init__(self, gui,) :
        self.root = gui
        self.bframe = Frame(self.root)  # Create a container Frame at bottom
        self.bframe.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        self.xlabel = Label(self.root, text="Item ID")  # Create the Label
        self.xlabel.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.xentry = Entry(self.root, bd=5)  # Create the Entry box
        self.xentry.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.xentry.bind('<Return>', self.showStockItem)
        self.xentry.focus_set()  # Set focus in the Entry box
        self.xopen = Button(self.root, text="Show", command=self.showStockItem) # Create the open Button
        self.xopen.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.xquit = Button(self.bframe, text="Quit", command=self.quitit) # Create the quit Button
        self.xquit.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        return

gui = Tk()
gui.title("Travel")
app = myApp(gui)
gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: And? Do you think it's wrong?

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: BTW: `__init__` doesn't need `return`

Comment: @furas: It's not a traceback, it's a warning from a linter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`from tkinter import *`

In this line, you import everything from `tkinter`. This is not recommended, so linter will warn you. But if you really want to do this, it's OK, just ignore it.

To be better, you should explicitly import what you need. For example:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Frame, Entry, Button
```

Answer (score 5):

Consider using:

```
import tkinter as tk
```

and then, prefix all your calls like:

```
root = tk.Tk()
```

or,

```
variableName.pack(side = tk.LEFT)
```

and so on...