# How to efficiently fix "undefined, or defined from * imports" warnings when loaded with "from variables import *"?

Tags: python, import

I have legacy code across >40 files that imports variables from a master 'variables.py' file using the `from variables import *` syntax. This import causes my IDE (Spyder) to give warnings like "undefined, or defined from * imports" for lines like `value = variable + 1`. *I understand that it is better to [name the variables explicitly in the imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47564740/variable-may-be-undefined-or-defined-from-star-imports-tkinter) and want to fix the issue efficiently.*

Is there an *efficient way* to fix these warnings across multiple files with many variables imported from this master variables.py (which contains >100 variables)? or is it better to go through these legacy files and explicitly name the variables as in the linked post?

Comment: Is variables.py literally just a list of variables or does it contain functions, classes as well? In either case, you can probably change `from variables import *` into `import variables as v` and then refactor all the `var1`, `var2` into `v.var1`, 'v.var2'... etc.  That's one way, but not necessarily the *most efficient way.*

Comment: Thank you. Yes, variables.py is literally just a list of variables.

Comment: `from variables import *` is completely unsafe. Assigning to those imported variables is not going to do what you want. Also, having a file full of hundreds of global variables you want to use everywhere is an incredibly noxious code smell.

Comment: I understand that this is legacy code and hopefully not your fault, but geeze.

Comment: How unsafe is this issue?

Comment: @kevins_1 generally speaking, you might be at risk of shadowing existing objects in your namespace.  e.g. if `list = 'something'` was defined in `variables.py` and you `from variable import *`, you'll no longer be able to use `list()` as the star import shadowed the `builtin` `list` function, and you would have no idea.

Comment: [Have a demo.](https://repl.it/repls/PersonalWorthlessProjector) You can see that `m1`'s assignment to `x` is not visible in `m2` in the demo.

Comment: @user2357112 that's an interesting demo, but technically they should be referred to as `m1.x` and `m2.x`, no? `x` doesn't exist in `main.py`, and `m1.set_x(5)` is just changing `m1.x` to `5`, whereas `m2.print_x()` is referencing `m2.x`.

Comment: @Idlehands: `m1` and `m2` have separate `x` variables, and `m1` is not assigning to the `x` variable that `m2` sees. From an outside module, these variables would be accessed as `m1.x` and `m2.x`. Incidentally, your answer silently changes the behavior of the assignments to `test` and `foo`, so I'm not sure whether you were thinking about this issue when you wrote that answer.

Comment: @user2357112 "your answer silent changes the behaviour of the assignments..." Would you mind to elaborate as a comment in my answer? And no, I wasn't cognitive of that, but I would like to know what other caveat I should be mindful of in such an operation (note it's not my preference, but technically it does answer OP's issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One riskier way you can do it is automate the refactoring (we'll define the risks later).  We'll use another Python script and the `re` module to accomplish this feat:

```
import re

# define all your critical variables here...
prefix = 'v'
pats = {
    'var': r'^([\w\d_]+) =',
    'cls': r'^class ([\w\d_]+)\(',
    'func': r'^def ([\w\d_]+)\('
}
objs = []
file_lists = ['full path to py #1 for refactor', 'full path to py #2 for refactor', 'etc...']
file = 'variables.py'
path = 'some/path/to/the/variables.py/module'

# load the contents of variables.py
with open('/'.join((path, file)), 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# extract all the objects with known patterns from the module
for line in lines:
    for pat in pats.values():
        found = re.search(pat, line)
        if found:
            objs.append(found.group(1)) # return the extracted object name

# iterate through the files requiring refactor
for fl in file_lists:
    with open(fl, 'r') as f:
        codes = f.read()

    # replace the star import with alias import
    codes = re.sub(r'from {module} import \*'.format(module=file.rstrip('.py')), 'import {module} as {pfx}'.format(module=file.rstrip('.py'), pfx=prefix), codes)

    # replace each object with their aliased alternative
    for obj in objs:
        codes = re.sub(r'(\b){var}(\b)'.format(var=obj), r'\1{pfx}.{o}\2'.format(pfx=prefix, o=obj), codes)

    # write to a NEW file, so you can compare and merge
    with open(fl.replace('.py','_refactored.py'), 'w') as f:
        f.write(codes)
```

**The biggest caveat of this is you are changing code without overseeing the changes.**  You might wish to add a `logger` so that each time a replacement was changed, you log what was changed and what's the replacement.  The second biggest caveat is this doesn't account for `strings` containing a match with the variable.  e.g. if you have a line of "This is a variable" and you want to replace obj `variable`, this execution will inadvertently change the `string` also.

Thus, even if you intend to go through with this exercise, it's best to compare your before and after and make any necessary fixes before you call it a final copy.  But it should accomplish 90% of the manual work required otherwise.

---

Here's a quick test:

#### variables.py content

```
class Bar():
    pass

def func():
    pass

test = 'hello'
foo = 'world'
```

#### codebase1.py:

```
from variables import *
                              # essentially they are:
test = 'something new'        # codebase1.test
Bar(test)                     # codebase1.Bar
func(foo)                     # codebase1.func
foo = 'Bar'                   # codebase1.foo
```

#### codebase1_refactored.py:

```
import variables as v
                              # essentially these are now:
v.test = 'something new'      # variables.test
v.Bar(v.test)                 # variables.Bar
v.func(v.foo)                 # variables.func
v.foo = 'v.Bar'               # variables.foo

# Note these are now directly referencing the objects within variables.py
# any reassignment/changes to these objects 
# will now have an impact on all other codebases
# that import from variables.py after the changes took place.

# Note also the string value for v.foo is also changed inadvertently.
```

## Edit:

As @user2357112 pointed out, another caveat is this will also subtly change the way assignments currently behave.  During a case of star import the objects that were imported (e.g. `test`) is in the scope of immediate code, and reassignments/changes to the object will not affect the scope of `variables.test`.  However with `v.test` it *does* directly mess with the `variables.test` object, and any other code importing variables afterwards will read the new assigned/changed object instead of from `variables.py`.

Comment: Be aware that by switching to `v.test = 'something new'`, you are now assigning to a different variable than the original code assigned to. You are assigning to the `variables.test` variable, rather than `codebase1.test`. This will be visible in other modules that use `variables.test`.

Comment: @user2357112 interesting, it seems the order of `import` matters in this case.  In your demo, if I `import m2` before I `import variables as v; v.x = 10` then `m2.x` will remain `0`.  However if I `import m2` after the reassignment, `m2.x` now returns `10`.  I would have imagined `m2` would try to `import` the module itself instead of the object that's already in memory.  I'm guessing that's to help reduce the memory footprint...

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this automated refactoring.