# Removing unused imports with pyflakes3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have [this](https://github.com/lucidl/tedegraph/blob/73b45ed16e9069f545c8539d5d65ec8a7f0fa49b/tdg.py) code and would like to remove unused imports.
When I run

```
pyflakes3 tdg.py
```

It shows me:

```
tdg.py:1: 'PyQt5.QtWidgets.QListWidget' imported but unused
tdg.py:1: 'PyQt5.QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem' imported but unused
tdg.py:1: 'PyQt5.QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView' imported but unused
tdg.py:3: 'PyQt5.QtGui.QIcon' imported but unused
tdg.py:4: 'from PyQt5.QtGui import *' used; unable to detect undefined names
tdg.py:5: 'from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *' used; unable to detect undefined names
tdg.py:15: 'QGraphicsView' may be undefined, or defined from star imports: PyQt5.QtGui, PyQt5.QtWidgets
tdg.py:21: 'QPainter' may be undefined, or defined from star imports: PyQt5.QtGui, PyQt5.QtWidgets
tdg.py:21: 'QPainter' may be undefined, or defined from star imports: PyQt5.QtGui, PyQt5.QtWidgets
tdg.py:24: 'QPalette' may be undefined, or defined from star imports: PyQt5.QtGui, PyQt5.QtWidgets
tdg.py:26: 'QGraphicsScene' may be undefined, or defined from star imports: PyQt5.QtGui, PyQt5.QtWidgets
tdg.py:29: 'QGraphicsPixmapItem' may be undefined, or defined from star imports: PyQt5.QtGui, PyQt5.QtWidgets
tdg.py:52: 'QtCore' may be undefined, or defined from star imports: PyQt5.QtGui, PyQt5.QtWidgets
tdg.py:54: 'QDialog' may be undefined, or defined from star imports: PyQt5.QtGui, PyQt5.QtWidgets
tdg.py:73: 'QFormLayout' may be undefined, or defined from star imports: PyQt5.QtGui, PyQt5.QtWidgets
tdg.py:104: 'QFrame' may be undefined, or defined from star imports: PyQt5.QtGui, PyQt5.QtWidgets
tdg.py:109: 'QFont' may be undefined, or defined from star imports: PyQt5.QtGui, PyQt5.QtWidgets
tdg.py:210: local variable 'pixmap' is assigned to but never used
tdg.py:337: 'QMessageBox' may be undefined, or defined from star imports: PyQt5.QtGui, PyQt5.QtWidgets
```

How to find out what can be removed, without running the code? Is `pyflakes3` sufficient or is there some better tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QListWidget`, `QListWidgetItem`, `QAbstractItemView` and `QIcon` imports can be removed. Also the variable `pixmap` can be removed as it's "never used".

To fix the warnings about star imports, explicitly define the imports like this:

```py
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPalette, QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsScene, QFrame, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsPixmapItem, QDialog, QFormLayout, QMessageBox
from PyQt5 import QtCore
```

and then remove the star imports.

Comment: But there are more things that the application don't use. Is it possible that pyflakes3 don't see them?

Comment: You probably aren't using everything from the star imports. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47564898/8890345) to a related question (although about Tkinter) says you should explicitly import what you need instead of using star imports.